# Adwords vs Bing Impressions

Tags: google-ads-api, bing, click-through, bing-ads-api

I run two ad campaigns, one each on Bing and Adwords with nearly the same ads, same keywords.  on Adwords I only use the search network.

A specific keyword gets me about 80% traffic from both sites, but this particular keyword, the impression count is CRAZY high on Bing, which results in crazy low CTR.

For example:

Adwords: 104/1404 (clicks vs impressions)

Bing Ads: 190/31,388 (clicks vs impressions)

Both for the last 7 days.

My ad position is very close to the same in both 1.6 vs 1.53 adwords/bing, and 
my quality score for both is 10/10

So what is going on with Bing?  Is this because there's no option to turn off the display network, and all of those impressions are getting added to that count?  Is this something I should be concerned about since I'm still driving traffic, and quality score is 10?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can see who is triggering that amount of impressions by "search partner". [Bing Ads publisher report](https://advertise.bingads.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/post/may-2014/bing-ads-academy-website-url-(publisher)-report)

On the other hand you actually can turn off the "search partners" on Bing. [Ad distribution](https://help.bingads.microsoft.com/apex/index/3/en-us/50871/)

Comment: perfect, thank you so much, exactly what I wanted to know.